# Arduino - unable to connect to wifi

Tags: string, arduino, char, wifi

I have this (partial) code, that is used to read the ssid and password from a text file on a SD card.
This data should then be used to connect to the local wifi. But it is unable to connect, and keeps saying "Establishing connection to WiFi..."

I also dont seem to be able to print what I have read from the SD card. Previously my readline function returned a string. That I was able to print properly and verified that the file is read as expected. Then, since wifi requires a Char* I changed the code to Char* and since then it didnt work anymore:

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <AccelStepper.h>
#include <MultiStepper.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
File myFile;
char* ssid;
char* password;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  pinMode(thetaPos, INPUT);
  pinMode(rhoPos, INPUT);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  if (!SD.begin()) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    while (1);

  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");
  myFile = SD.open("/config.txt");
  if (myFile) {
    // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    ssid = readLine();
    password = readLine();
    
      Serial.println(ssid);
      Serial.println(password);
  
  connectToNetwork();

    
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();
  } else {
    // file didn't open       
  }
 }
 
void loop() {
}


char* readLine() {
  char* received = "";
  char ch;
  while (myFile.available()) {
    ch = myFile.read();
    if (ch == '\n') {
      return received;
    } else {
      received += ch;
    }
  }
  return received;
}

void connectToNetwork() {
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Establishing connection to WiFi..");
  }
 
  Serial.println("Connected to network");
 
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

this is the serial output:

```
Initializing SD card...initialization done.
ore calibration nvs commit failed(0x%x)


wdt_config->intr_handle)
Establishing connection to WiFi..
Establishing connection to WiFi..
Establishing connection to WiFi..
Establishing connection to WiFi..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, where is the error? This won't work as you hope:

```
char* readLine() {
  char* received = "";         // poiner to \0 somewhere... 
  char ch;
  while (myFile.available()) {
    ch = myFile.read();
    if (ch == '\n') {
      return received;
    } else {
      received += ch;          // move pointer to location ch bytes after...
    }
  }
  return received;
}
```

You are utilizing pointer arithmetic - you are moving pointer around the memory and you are not storing anything anywhere. It's not String class that overloads `+= char` and allows you to concatenate character to the end of it.

Basically you can use:

```
String readLine() {
  String received;
  while (myFile.available()) {
    ch = myFile.read();
    if (ch == '\n') {
      return received;
    } else {
      received += ch;
    }
  }
  return received;
}
```

and it'll work (althrough it's not a good idea to append character by character to the String - heap memory gets fragmented really fast by this approach)

To avoid other mistakes, usage is something like:

```
String ssid = readLine();
String pass = readLine();

Wifi.begin(ssid.c_str(), pass.c_str());

//// definitely do not do something like:
// Wifi.begin(readLine().c_str(), readLine().c_str()); // !!! WRONG !!!
//// as the order of executing parameters isn't specified (and in the GCC it's from the last to the first)
```

Comment: uhm, spoke too early.. sorry.. actually the `Wifi.begin(ssid.c_str(), pass.c_str());` does not work.. if i replace them with char* and write the value into them then i cann connect without problems..

Comment: Serial.print('|'); Serial.print(ssid); Serial.print('|'); Serial.print(pass); Serial.println('|'); If it prints anything more than  |myssid|mypass|, then you forgot about \r\n (line separator in windows)

Comment: all seems correct... `|Bill Clinternet|testpass|
Establishing connection to WiFi..
Establishing connection to WiFi..
`still not connecting..

Comment: oh, the pass was wrong.. sorrrry it works now... thank you!

Comment: I just noticed the note you wrote in the last section, about the order of execution.. I am not sure I understood that.. the program is working fine now, i would just like to learn as much as possible and understand that. could you please explain what you meant? thank you

Comment: Basically if you do: `Wifi.begin(getLine(), getLine());`  you can get `begin` called either  with `("ssid", "pass")` or with `("pass", "ssid")` as the order is not specified. It depends on the used compiler.

Comment: ohh ok got it.. thank you very much! so I guess that this would be the same situation: `if ((myFile.name() != "/config.txt") && (myFile.isDirectory() == false))` right?

Comment: This one shouldn't be a problem. It depends on "side effects" - function changes something that others are using too. But && and || are "short circuit evaluated", so if the first part of expresion is false, nothing else can change it and it'll skip the rest of it. Eg.  false && something()  won't call something. Maybe check that logic..  if it's not a /config.txt then check if it's not a directory?

Comment: well on that particular expression I have the inverse problem. the file is called config.txt but the code inside the IF is executed anyway... but thats a different story.. thank you for your time KIIV! :)